# How can I pull individual characters from a string and convert them to numbers?

Tags: android, arrays, string

What I'm trying to do is find a way I can take the word "camel" for example from a EditText field and make for instance c=2 a=1 m=4 e=5 l=3. Is there anyway I can pull the individual characters from a string and convert them to numbers?

I've tried using "split" to separate each character into an array but I can't figure out how to convert the letters into numbers 
so I can do something like:

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
int temp = (int)(array[1]+array[2]+array[3]+etc...)
```

using the example of "camel" would equal 15

This is what I have so far:

```
String name = inputarea.getText().toString();
String[] array = name.split("");
for(int i =0; i < array.length ; i++)
```

The biggest problem I keep having is if I try to pull from the 7th position in the array and nothing is there. (camel only has 5 characters) then I get a nice big error.

Thank you for any help that can be provided.

Edit: I figured it out after a few hours of playing with it here is my working code:

```
String firstname = inputarea.getText().toString();
char[] array = firstname.toCharArray();
final char[] array2 = new char[15];
System.arraycopy(array, 0, array2, 0, array.length);            
if (array2[0] == 'A' ) {
array2[0] = '1';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

suggestion:

first, need define all letter, from a-z (A-Z), the ASCII code 'a' to 'z' is 97 to 122, if you want support the upper letter, you need add A-Z.

then, get the letter in the string, u can use this:

```
for(int i=0;i<string.length();i++){
        int number = string.charAt(i);
}
```

when you get the number size, you can reduce to the base number('a' is 97), you will get the individual number

Comment: And if the user really does want '1' to be 'a', they can append "- 96" to the charAt line to bring the values down.

Answer (score 0):

Does String.charAt() works for you?

As for converting to number, if the numbers are consecutive you can define a fixed string with all the characters you want to map and use String.indexOf(). If not, you can have a parallel array with ints or use a Map.